# Empty body in Boost::ASIO HTTP POST

Tags: c++, http, boost

I tried using Post method with the below code. On the server side the body is always empty.

```
tcp::endpoint ip_port(address::from_string(host), port);
socket.connect(ip_port);

boost::asio::streambuf request;
std::ostream request_stream(&request);

request_stream << "POST /myservice HTTP/1.1\n\n";
request_stream << "Host:" << "host:port" << "\r\n";
request_stream << "User-Agent: C/1.0" << "\r\n";
request_stream << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n";
request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
request_stream << "Content-Length: ";
request_stream << json.length() + "\r\n";
request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"; 
request_stream << json;

boost::asio::write(socket, request);
```

I checked on server side by sending request from other rest client, it works fine. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Perhaps add `request_stream << std::flush;` just before `boost::asio::write`.

Comment: @Mankarse tried it, getting same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found it. The problem with \n\n in the first line. If there are two \n, request ends there. I tried the below code and I'm able to get the json body on server side.

```
requestStream << "POST " << "/myservice" << " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
requestStream << "Host: " << "myhost" << "\r\n";
requestStream << "Accept: application/json\r\n";
requestStream << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
requestStream << "Content-Length: " << json.length() << "\r\n";
requestStream << "\r\n";
requestStream << json << "\n\n";
```